# Fitting a gnuplottex figure in a beamer slide

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

I am designing a slide in beamer, where I want to plot a 3D figure.

My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

My slide code is as follows:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Illustration of 3D plot}{Rastrigin's function}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex,terminaloptions={color size=\textheight,\textheight}]
            set xrange [-5.6:5.6]
            set yrange [-5.6:5.6]
            set ticslevel 0
            f(x,y) = 20 + x**2 - 10 * cos(2 * pi * x) + y**2 - 10 * cos(2*pi *y) 
            set pm3d
            set isosample 100
            set hidden3d
            legend off
            set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
            splot f(x,y)  
        \end{gnuplot}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

The trouble is that the 3D plot wouldn't fit in the slide, even though I have attempted multiple combinations.

OS: Sierra / 64 bit / GNUPLOT on MAC / TexLive 2015

Answer (score 3):

I get a result with

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Illustration of 3D plot}{Rastrigin's function}
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex,terminaloptions={color size 9cm,7.25cm}]
  set xrange [-5.6:5.6]
  set yrange [-5.6:5.6]
  set ticslevel 0
  f(x,y) = 20 + x**2 - 10 * cos(2 * pi * x) + y**2 - 10 * cos(2*pi *y)
  set pm3d
  set isosample 100
  set hidden3d
  set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
  unset key
  splot f(x,y)
\end{gnuplot}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The size cannot be given in terms of `\textheight` (not that way, at least).

I also get an error at `legend off`, but probably it depends on the fact I have gnuplot 5.0 that uses `unset key`.

The font is too big, find the way to make it smaller.

[image]

Comment: Maybe also draw attention to the explicit size.  With `{color size=\textheight,\textheight}` I get an error during compilation.